# Electric Adapter for Japan

Tags: international-travel, japan, electronic-items, power

I live in Germany and I already have a universal travel adapter as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Since the voltage level in Germany is 230V and in Japan it's 110V, do I need any other special arrangement. Is it safe to charge mobile, iPad at nearly half the voltage levels?

Comment: Good news - every laptop/phone/etc charger made in the last, say, 10 years, supports all voltages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This Adapter is just a connector and it does not do any voltage conversion for you. If your device does not support 110V operation this adapter will still not help you.

However most new Laptops and mobile phones come with support for a broad voltage from 100 to 240V and you can check on the chargers if they are of the same category. If so, you’re good to go.

Apple chargers [do support 100 - 240V](https://www.apple.com/power-adapters/) input so you're good for an iPhone or an iPad at least.

Comment: Also, the consequences of plugging a 230 V appliance into 110 V are not that severe compared to the other way round.